# Override Object Property for unit testing purposes

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, object-properties

I am using Jest to perform unit tests on a Node.js app, where the code source is written in TypeScript and then compiled into JavaScript.

In one of the classes that I wish to test, an external module is imported and a method from this module is used. I want to mock the calls to this method, in order to test only my code.

However, when I run the test, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot redefine property: methodName`

The problem is that this method has the following Object Properties:

```
{ value: [Function],
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false }
```

The `configurable: false` is what makes it a big problem. I cannot redefine the properties before my mock call to make it writable.

Here is what the relevant code looks like:

**Tested Class**

```
import externalType from 'external-module-name';

export class ClassName {
    public propertyName: externalType;

    public method(param: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.propertyName.externalMethod(param)
            .then((res) => {
                resolve(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
import { ClassName } from 'path/to/class';

describe('class', () => {
    const class = new ClassName;

    it("Blahblah", (done) => {
        Object.defineProperty(class['propertyName'], 'externalMethod', {writable: true});
        const spy = jest.spyOn(class['propertyName'], 'externalMethod').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve());
        class.method('string')
        .then((result) => {
            // Various expect()
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

**What I tried so far**

1. I added the following line in my test:

   `Object.defineProperty(class['module'], 'methodName', {writable: true});`
2. I defined my mock call as following:

   `jest.spyOn(class['module'], 'methodName').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve());`
3. I defined my mock call as following:

   `class.propertyName.externalMethod = jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => {
       return Promise.resolve();
   });`
4. I tried to override the property that I'm calling, as following:

   `class.propertyName = <any> {
       externalMethod = (param: any) => {
           return Promise.resolve();
       }
   }`

For this one I get the error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property externalMethod of object class`, which makes sense since readable is set to false.

But everything seems blocked from the attribute `configurable`. I'm sure there is something that can be done because I am probably not the only one who wants to perform unit tests on a class that imports an external module, as secure as it is.

So my question is: **what would be a clean and working way of mocking the external method?** And if it is strictly impossible, **what would be a way of testing my class without calling that external method?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I found that by doing:

```js
jest.mock('path/to/class');
```

I was able to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but until I have a cleaner solution, the following has been an acceptable stop-gap:

```
let override: boolean | undefined;

static before() {
    Object.defineProperty(module, 'readonlyProperty', {
        get() {
            return this.override;
        }
    });
}

@test
public test() {
    this.override = false;
    expect(module.readonlyProperty).to.be.false;
}
```

---- UPDATE ----

If using sinon sandboxes, use the `replace` API

```
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
sandbox.replace(module, 'readonlyProperty', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
// ========= Mock Object.defineProperty to always allow overriding =========
const originalDefineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
const originalDefineProperties = Object.defineProperties;
Object.defineProperty = (obj, prop, desc) => {
   try {
     return originalDefineProperty(obj, prop, {...desc, configurable: true});
   } catch(e) {
    return originalDefineProperty(obj, prop, desc);
   }
};
Object.defineProperties = (obj, props) => {
  const propsCopy = {...props};
  Object.keys(propsCopy).forEach((key) => {
    propsCopy[key].configurable = true;
  });
  try {
    return originalDefineProperties(obj, propsCopy);
  } catch(e) {
    return originalDefineProperties(obj, props);
  }
};
// =========================================================================
```

You need to apply it as soon as possible in your tests. If you are using jest, you can put this code snippet inside a js file and load it using "setupFiles" prop in jest config.