# jest - how to avoid using a spy for a getter

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I have this

```js
jest.spyOn(store.customerData, "isValid", "get").mockReturnValue(true);
```

that I'd like to refactor to use a typical `jest.fn()` mock like this:

```js
store.customerData.isValid = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true)
```

but I get an error claiming that the property is read only.

Comment: Can you add the minimal code which you want to test and the error detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the `ObjectProperties` of your method.

If the `configurable` attribute is set to `true`, you can try using [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(store['customerData'], 'isValid', {writable: true});
// And then put your code
store.customerData.isValid = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);
```

If it's set to `false`, I'm afraid I don't have any solution. I had a problem close to yours a few months ago (that I did not resolve) and I asked a question on SO, you can check what I tried, see if anything works for you: [Override Object Property for unit testing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755086/override-object-property-for-unit-testing-purposes)